# MultipleApiVersions not working in OWIN

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I am struggling to get Swagger to document multi-tenanted routes in WebApi.I have used this approach before but never in a self-hosted project. It seems `MultipleApiVersions` is never invoked - when i've added logging code.

StatupConfig.cs

```
 public class StartupConfig
    {
        private static ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(nameof(StartupConfig));

        public void Configure(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Filters.Add(new ApiKeyAuthorizationFilter());
            config.Filters.Add(new ApiInvocationMetricsFilter());

            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(assembly);
            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();

            var container = builder.Build();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);


            appBuilder.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
            appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

            config
             .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                   c.MultipleApiVersions(
                          ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint,
                          (vc) =>
                          {
                              vc.Version("v2", "API v2");
                              vc.Version("v1", "API v1");
                          });
                    c.RootUrl((message) => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SwaggerRoot"]);
                    c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\API.xml");
                    c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredApiKeyParameter>();
                    c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings(true);
                })
             .EnableSwaggerUi(ui =>
                {
                    ui.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector();
                });
        }

        public static bool ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint(ApiDescription apiDesc, string targetApiVersion)
        {
            try
            {
                var versionConstraint = (apiDesc.Route.Constraints.ContainsKey("apiVersion"))
                ? apiDesc.Route.Constraints["apiVersion"] as ApiVersionConstraint
                : null;

                return versionConstraint?.AllowedVersion.Split('|').Select(x => x.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList().Contains(targetApiVersion.ToLowerInvariant()) ?? false;
            }
            catch (System.Exception excep)
            {
                _logger.Error("An error occurred resolving version support", excep);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: This predates WebApiVersioning so I am using a route constraint:

```
     public class ApiVersion2RoutePrefixAttribute : RoutePrefixAttribute
  {
    private const string RouteBase = "api/{apiVersion:apiVersionConstraint(v2)}";
    private const string PrefixRouteBase = "api/{apiVersion:apiVersionConstraint(v2)}/";

    public ApiVersion2RoutePrefixAttribute(string routePrefix)
      : base(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(routePrefix) ? "api/{apiVersion:apiVersionConstraint(v2)}" : "api/{apiVersion:apiVersionConstraint(v2)}/" + routePrefix)
    {
    }
  }
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks
KH

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by ensuring any `Name` parameters in the `Route` attribute are unique across both controller versions. I had an operation named Add, with a Route Name parameter of Add across both controllers and this was preventing Swagger from functioning.

i.e this

`[Route("", Name = nameof(AddAdvertiser))]`

changed to this

`[Route("", Name = nameof(V1AddAdvertiser))]`